# Should I get a Populist badge for this answer?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, badges

So here's what happened...

I answered this question: 
[Why didn't Walter White consume his own product?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26457/why-didnt-walter-white-consume-his-own-product)

I originally got my answer accepted.  However, for whatever reason the OP changed his mind and awarded the accepted answer to someone else.

However, I now have a score of more than 10, and it's got more than 2X the checkmarks as the now-accepted answer.

Am I eligible for the Populist badge, or do I not get it because it was originally an accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [meta-stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), to qualify for the Populist badge, you need:

> - it is the highest scoring answer on the question TRUE
> - it does not have the accepted checkmark TRUE
> - it has a score of 23 or more FALSE
> - it has more than double the score of the accepted answer TRUE
> - the accepted answer has a score of 11 or more FALSE
> - it is not an answer to your own question (source) TRUE

Since it currently fails two of the criteria,  it doesn't qualify unfortunately.

Comment: Ahh...  The other description isn't as...  descriptive.  http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist

Comment: @JohnnyBones - agreed, it certainly is not!

Comment: How about now?  LOL.  Just noticed that my answer now meets all criteria.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - well, I see you don't have it yet.  I wonder if "more than double" is the problem now, its 12/24 - exactly double.  Let me go and upvote it.